# Registry Entries for Audio Settings

Tags: c#, audio, registry, device

Does anyone know how to interpret the settings for the installed audio devices in the registry. I'm pretty sure that the settings I want to look at are under Capture and Render respectively at:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio

However, while I can see the devices and identify them by name I cannot locate the settings for the devices. Even translating the hex values doesn't render any useful information.

Are the actual settings, e.g. volume, boost, sample rate, stored somewhere else?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use API, the intended way to access settings?

Comment: Most hardware audio settings are not readily available through an API and some not at all. This is apparently an intentional choice by MS to not make them available.